# out of memory with spring jdbctemplate.batchupdate(sql,List<Object[]>)

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

My application run every 5 mins for the same data(may change a little bit) load to be inserted into DB.

When using Spring batch to insert the rows memory consumption remain fine and memory is garbage collected so the next run does not see a memory spike.

However while doing batchupdate manually using Spring's jdbctemplate.batchupdate(), I see the memory takes a long time to get GC.

Any hints on what's happening?

Comment: Too much data in memory. Spring Batch and `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` aren't the same thing!.

Comment: Are these known issues where GC takes a long time to claim the memory in case of jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate vs Spring Batch's batch update?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the use of `batchUpdate` it has to do with the fact that you have too many entries at once in memory. As stated you are comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using JdbcTemplate batchUpdate method (`batchUpdate(String sql, final Collection<T> batchArgs, final int batchSize, final ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<T> pss)`).

But I did manage the resolve it with the accurate settings of heap size (based on object and batch size) and providing clearParameters (ParameterDisposer) method implementation to release resources allocated to parameters.

My custom ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter implements both ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter and ParameterDisposer.

Comment: 1. Could you please explain why parameters were to be disposed? Weren't they just garbage collected?